@nativescript-community/ui-material-bottomsheet crashes on iOS with "MDCBottomSheetControllerDelegate is not defined"
I am trying to use the @nativescript-community/ui-material-bottomsheet plugin in my NativeScript Angular app. The plugin works perfectly on Android, but it crashes on iOS when calling the install() method in my main.ts file.
I receive the following error on iOS:

NativeScript discarding uncaught JS exception!
Error loading bottom sheet module: ReferenceError: MDCBottomSheetControllerDelegate is not defined

In my package.json,

"@nativescript-community/ui-material-bottomsheet": "^6.2.3",
"@nativescript-community/ui-material-core": "^6.2.3",
"@nativescript/ios": "8.5.2",
"@nativescript/core": "^7.3.0",

my main.ts file is giving below,
import { Application } from '@nativescript/core';
import { Theme } from "@nativescript/theme";
import { ios } from '@nativescript/core/application';
import { init } from "@nativescript/background-http";
import { install } from "@nativescript-community/ui-material-bottomsheet";

if (Application.android) {
    init();
    setTimeout(() => {
        Theme.setMode(Theme.Light);
    }, 100);
    install(); // Works fine on Android
} else {
    @NativeClass()
    class MyDelegate extends UIResponder implements UIApplicationDelegate {
        public static ObjCProtocols = [UIApplicationDelegate];
        public ObjCExposedMethods = {
            "runOnBackground": { returns: interop.types.void }
        };
        private bgTask;
        private timer;
        private timerCounter;

        applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions(
            application: UIApplication,
            launchOptions: NSDictionary<any, any>
        ): boolean {
            console.log("applicationWillFinishLaunchingWithOptions: " + launchOptions);
            return true;
        }
        applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication): void {
            console.log("applicationDidBecomeActive: " + application);
            if (this.timer) {
                clearInterval(this.timer);
            }
        }
        public applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {
            console.log("App entered background.");
            this.bgTask = application.beginBackgroundTaskWithNameExpirationHandler("MyTask", () => {
                this.endBackgroundTask();
            });
            this.timerCounter = 5;
            this.timer = setInterval(() => {
                this.runOnBackground();
            }, 5000);
        }
        private endBackgroundTask(): void {
            this.timerCounter = 5;
            UIApplication.sharedApplication.endBackgroundTask(this.bgTask);
            this.bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
            console.log("End of background task.");
        }
        public runOnBackground(): void {
            if (this.timerCounter <= 0) {
                this.endBackgroundTask();
                return;
            }
            console.log(`${this.timerCounter} (the app is in background)`);
            this.timerCounter--;
        }
    }

    ios.delegate = MyDelegate;
    install(); // Crashes on iOS with "MDCBottomSheetControllerDelegate is not defined"
}

I have tried cleaning the project and reinstalling platforms, but the issue persists.
I would appreciate any suggestions or guidance on resolving the MDCBottomSheetControllerDelegate is not defined error on iOS. Is there a missing configuration or additional setup required for iOS?
Thank you!
What I’ve Tried:

I have added and removed the plugin multiple times.
I checked the import and tried adding & removing NativeScriptMaterialBottomSheetModule.forRoot() from root.module.ts
Cleaned and rebuilt the project.
Verified that all the necessary steps were followed, including adding install() in the main.ts file.
Double-checked my package.json dependencies.

I would appreciate any suggestions or guidance on resolving the MDCBottomSheetControllerDelegate is not defined error on iOS. Is there a missing configuration or additional setup required for iOS?
Thank you!
